# How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?

Tags: shell, command-line, arithmetic, floating-point, calculator

Using `echo "20+5"` literally produces the text "`20+5`".

What command can I use to get the numeric sum, `25` in this case?

Also, what's the easiest way to do it just using bash for floating
point? For example, `echo $((3224/3807.0))` prints `0` :(.

I am looking for answers using either the basic command shell ('command
line') itself or through using languages that are available from the
command line.

Comment: If you're going with `bc`, it may be worth your while to read about the `-l` option in the man page.

Comment: I assume author is asking for bash command line, while answers all tend to diversify to all kinds of scripting languages.

Comment: man bash → /expression

Comment: @zinking Well, bash is designed to be conveniently able to easily invoke the interpreters for a large number of other scripting language.

Comment: Teach bash integer division with floating point results: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24431665/3776858

Comment: I like to use pythonpy (https://github.com/russell91/pythonpy) for my calculator: py 3224/3807 => 0.846861045443. py 'math.factorial(4)' => 24.

Comment: See also [How to round floating point numbers in the shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167058/23408).

Comment: I came here because [bash can't multiply floats, only integers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159161/24170).

Comment: I really don't like how this part of the question "...or other languages/frameworks?" opened the gates of hell to answers for all kind of languages/frameworks.

Comment: see also [How do I use floating-point arithmetic in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-arithmetic-in-bash)

Answer (score 586, accepted):

### There are lots of options!!!

### Summary

```
$ printf %.10f\\n "$((10**9 * 20/7))e-9"   # many shells. Not mksh.
$ echo "$((20.0/7))"                       # (ksh93/zsh/yash, some bash)
$ awk "BEGIN {print (20+5)/2}"
$ zcalc
$ bc <<< 20+5/2
$ bc <<< "scale=4; (20+5)/2"
$ dc <<< "4 k 20 5 + 2 / p"
$ expr 20 + 5
$ calc 2 + 4
$ node -pe 20+5/2  # Uses the power of JavaScript, e.g. : node -pe 20+5/Math.PI
$ echo 20 5 2 / + p | dc 
$ echo 4 k 20 5 2 / + p | dc 
$ perl -E "say 20+5/2"
$ python -c "print(20+5/2)"
$ python -c "print(20+5/2.0)"
$ clisp -x "(+ 2 2)"
$ lua -e "print(20+5/2)"
$ php -r 'echo 20+5/2;'
$ ruby -e 'p 20+5/2'
$ ruby -e 'p 20+5/2.0'
$ guile -c '(display (+ 20 (/ 5 2)))'
$ guile -c '(display (+ 20 (/ 5 2.0)))'
$ slsh -e 'printf("%f",20+5/2)'
$ slsh -e 'printf("%f",20+5/2.0)'
$ tclsh <<< 'puts [expr 20+5/2]'
$ tclsh <<< 'puts [expr 20+5/2.0]'
$ sqlite3 <<< 'select 20+5/2;'
$ sqlite3 <<< 'select 20+5/2.0;'
$ echo 'select 1 + 1;' | sqlite3 
$ psql -tAc 'select 1+1'
$ R -q -e 'print(sd(rnorm(1000)))'
$ r -e 'cat(pi^2, "\n")'
$ r -e 'print(sum(1:100))'
$ smjs
$ jspl
$ gs -q  <<< "5 2 div 20 add  ="
```

### Details

#### Shells

You can use POSIX arithmetic expansion for *integer* arithmetic **`echo "$((...))"`**:

```
$ echo "$((20+5))"
25
$ echo "$((20+5/2))"
22
```

---

Quite portable (**`ash dash yash bash ksh93 lksh zsh`**):
Using printf ability to print floats we can extend most shells to do floating point math albeit with a limited range (no more than 10 digits):

```
$ printf %.10f\\n "$((1000000000 *   20/7  ))e-9"
2.8571428570
```

---

**`ksh93`**, **`yash`** and **`zsh`** do support floats here:

```
$ echo "$((1.2 / 3))"
0.4
```

only **`ksh93`** (directly) and **`zsh`** loading library mathfunc here:

```
$ echo "$((4*atan(1)))"
3.14159265358979324
```

(`zsh` need to load `zmodload zsh/mathfunc` to get functions like `atan` ).

---

Interactively with zsh:

```
$ autoload zcalc
$ zcalc
1> PI/2
1.5708
2> cos($1)
6.12323e-17
3> :sci 12
6.12323399574e-17
```

---

With (t)csh (integer only):

```
% @ a=25 / 3; echo $a
8
```

---

In the `rc` shell family, `akanga` is the one with arithmetic expansion:

```
; echo $:25/3
8
```

---

#### POSIX toolchest

**`bc`** (see below for interactive mode), [manual here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html)

Mnemonic: <kbd>b</kbd>est <kbd>c</kbd>alculator (though the `b` is in fact for *basic*).

```
$ echo 20+5/2 | bc
22
$ echo 'scale=4;20+5/2' | bc
22.5000
```

(supports arbitrary precision numbers)

---

bc interactive mode:

```
$ bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
5+5
10

2.2+3.3
5.5
```

---

[Rush](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13003/rush)'s solution, **`expr`** (no interactive mode):

```
$ expr 20 + 5
25
$ expr 20 + 5 / 2
22
```

---

[Joshua's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40897): **`awk`** (no interactive mode):

```
$ calc() { awk "BEGIN{print $*}"; }
$ calc 1/3
0.333333
```

#### Other more or less portable tools

[Arcege](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4194/arcege)'s solution, **`dc`** (interactive mode: `dc`):

Which is even more fun since it works by reverse polish notation.

```
$ echo 20 5 2 / + p | dc 
22
$ echo 4 k 20 5 2 / + p | dc 
22.5000
```

But not as practical unless you work with reverse polish notation a lot.

<sup>Note that `dc` predates `bc` and `bc` has been historically implemented as a wrapper around `dc` but `dc` was not standardised by POSIX</sup>

---

[DQdims](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6234/dqdlm)'s **`calc`** (required `sudo apt-get install apcalc)`:

```
$ calc 2 + 4
6
```

#### General purpose language interpreters:

[manatwork](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10412/manatwork)'s solution, **`node`** (interactive mode: `node`; output function not needed):

```
$ node -pe 20+5/2  # Uses the power of JavaScript, e.g. : node -pe 20+5/Math.PI
22.5
```

---

**Perl** (interactive mode: `perl -de 1`):

```
$ perl -E "say 20+5/2"
22.5
```

---

**Python** (interactive mode: `python`; output function not needed):

```
$ python -c "print(20+5/2)"
22 # 22.5 with python3
$ python -c "print(20+5/2.0)"
22.5
```

Also supports arbitrary precision numbers:

```
$ python -c 'print(2**1234)'
295811224608098629060044695716103590786339687135372992239556207050657350796238924261053837248378050186443647759070955993120820899330381760937027212482840944941362110665443775183495726811929203861182015218323892077355983393191208928867652655993602487903113708549402668624521100611794270340232766099317098048887493809023127398253860618772619035009883272941129544640111837184
```

---

If you have **`clisp`** installed, you can also use polish notation:

```
$ clisp -x "(+ 2 2)"
```

---

[Marco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12779/marco)'s solution, **`lua`** (interactive mode: `lua`):

```
$ lua -e "print(20+5/2)"
22.5
```

---

**PHP** (interactive mode: `php -a`):

```
$ php -r 'echo 20+5/2;'
22.5
```

---

**Ruby** (interactive mode: `irb`; output function not needed):

```
$ ruby -e 'p 20+5/2'
22
$ ruby -e 'p 20+5/2.0'
22.5
```

---

**Guile** (interactive mode: `guile`):

```
$ guile -c '(display (+ 20 (/ 5 2)))'
45/2
$ guile -c '(display (+ 20 (/ 5 2.0)))'
22.5
```

---

**S-Lang** (interactive mode: `slsh`; output function not needed, just a `;` terminator):

```
$ slsh -e 'printf("%f",20+5/2)'
22.000000
$ slsh -e 'printf("%f",20+5/2.0)'
22.500000
```

---

**Tcl** (interactive mode: `tclsh`; output function not needed, but `expr` is):

```
$ tclsh <<< 'puts [expr 20+5/2]'
22
$ tclsh <<< 'puts [expr 20+5/2.0]'
22.5
```

---

**Javascript** shells:

```
$ smjs
js> 25/3
8.333333333333334
js>

$ jspl
JSC: 25/3

RP: 8.33333333333333
RJS: [object Number]
JSC:
Good bye...

$ node
> 25/3
8.333333333333334
>
```

---

#### Various SQL's:

**SQLite** (interactive mode: `sqlite3`):

```
$ sqlite3 <<< 'select 20+5/2;'
22
$ sqlite3 <<< 'select 20+5/2.0;'
22.5
```

---

**MySQL**:

```
mysql -BNe 'select 1+1'
```

---

**PostgreSQL**:

```
psql -tAc 'select 1+1
```

_The options on mysql and postgres stop the 'ascii art' image !

#### Specialised math-oriented languages:

**R** in plain mode - lets generate 1000 Normal random numbers and get the standard deviation and print it

```
$ R -q -e 'print(sd(rnorm(1000)))'
> print(sd(rnorm(1000)))
[1] 1.031997
```

---

**R** using the **littler** script - lets print pi squared

```
$ r -e 'cat(pi^2, "\n")'
9.869604
$  r -e 'print(sum(1:100))'
[1] 5050
```

---

**PARI/GP**, an extensive computer algebra system for number theory, linear algebra, and many other things

```
$ echo "prime(1000)"|gp -q
7919                        // the 1000th prime
$ echo "factor(1000)" | gp -q
[2 3]
[5 3]                       // 2^3*5^3
$ echo "sum(x=1,5,x)" | gp -q
15                          // 1+2+3+4+5
```

---

**GNU Octave** (a high-level interpreted language, primarily intended for numerical computations)

Also supports complex numbers:

```
$ octave
>> 1.2 / 7
ans =  0.17143
>> sqrt(-1)
ans =  0 + 1i
```

---

**Julia**, high-performance language and interpreter for scientific and numerical computing.

Non-interactive option:

```
$ julia -E '2.5+3.7'
6.2
```

---

**GhostScript**
GhostScript is a PostScript interpreter, very commonly installed even in very old distributions.
See [PostScript docs](http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/Flat/math-ref.html) for a list of supported math commands.

Interactive example:

```
$ GS_DEVICE=display gs
GPL Ghostscript 9.07 (2013-02-14)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
GS>5 2 div 20 add  =
22.5
GS>
```

Comment: I also like the use of `<<<`, does this mean pipe it in AND execute the command?

Comment: That is a **Here String**. (From the manual:) `<<<word` is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input. Shorter than `echo ... |`.

Comment: As a variation on the bc approach, I added the following function (that I found on stackexchange somewhere) to my .bashrc file.  I can just enter calc 2+3 and get 5.  `## Command line calculator
calc () {
    bc -l <<< "$@"
}
`

Comment: If I would have enough reputation I would vote this down because it includes many commands which will not produce what we can say would be the expected output. Some will not even work at all (see answers below).

Comment: `echo "$((20.0/7))"` fails in bash and dash

Comment: sugest you removing bc without scale configuration as bc without scaling doesn't perform division correctly (it rounds floor), so bc <<< 20+5/2 = fail

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas great answer!  However I couldn't find a solution / answer for fish shell   => http://fishshell.com/

Comment: @Chris, fish is a moving target. They're working on their new `math` builtin (or whatever it's called now) as we speak. Feel free to edit. It's not my answer and it's community wiki.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yeah doing a search on this page for `fish` got me to the right place. ;)

Comment: Great post, but IMHO none of these are convenient in the 21st century.  bc should default to scale=4 as a default.

Comment: Since all the solutions have notorious drawbacks, I have created a new command for this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577257/223253

Comment: Why are you using bashism in examples where it's not needed?

Comment: @done The commands are not duplicates. Intentionally, there are two sequential commands of the same type to show the interger and decimal division. For example `bc` without `-l` and `bc` with `scale` (not the whole `-l`). Similar for the `python` commands, the first one is integer dividion by purpose.

Comment: @thanasisp, though there's `dc <<< "4 k 20 5 + 2 / p"` and `echo 4 k 20 5 2 / + p | dc`, which are just two ways of doing the same thing (apart from the (20+5)/2 vs. 20+5/2 distinction). The former doesn't have the integer equivalent, and the other tools don't have the variants with `echo`, just the nonstandard here-string ones. The Python thing case might warrant a comment because of the Python 2 vs. 3 difference, and well, `dc`'s `k` might warrant a note too, though since it's RPN, I guess it can just be left obscure too. (Also the `dc <<<` isn't mentioned in the longer descriptions.)

Comment: (Saying that kinda makes me think I should go through the whole list, and besides it would be nice to have them all spell out the same expression... but I don't think I can be bothered right now. )

Comment: @ilkkachu I rolled back last change for the reason I explain into my comment. For example, it modified the `bc` example for integer division to `bc -l` which is decimal. If you or anyone think of any improvement, please do it.

Comment: @thanasisp, yes, and I'm saying not all of your arguments seem to apply, for the reasons I explained.

Answer (score 46):

There are many ways to calculate.
For simple expressions you can use `bash` itself:

```
echo $((20+5))
```

or `expr`:

```
expr 20 + 5
```

And for complex cases there is great tool `bc`:

```
echo "20+5" | bc
```

Btw, bc can calculate even very complex expression with roots, logarithms, cos, sin and so on.

Comment: I added your `expr` option to the accepted answer.  Had to pick one to accept and centralize.

Answer (score 34):

Nobody has mentioned awk yet?

Using POSIX shell functions, and awk math power, just define this (one line) function:

```
calc(){ awk "BEGIN { print $*}"; }
```

Then just execute things like `calc 1+1` or `calc 5/2`

Note: To make the function always available, add it to ~/.bashrc (or your corresponding shell's startup file)

Of course, a little script named "calc" with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh -
awk "BEGIN { print $* }"
```

could also work.

Comment: Wow this is the best, even supports floats. It works without installing anything!

Comment: Very nice, I wanted to have a floating comparison, here is how I did it with your help: `a=0; b=0.0; if echo "$a" "$b" | awk '{ exit ($1 == $2) ? 0 : 1 }'; then echo 'equals'; else echo 'not equals'; fi`

Comment:  As command: https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/calc

Answer (score 29):

The mentioned solutions are fine for very simple calculations, but very error-prone. Examples:

```
# without spaces expr 20+5 produces literally 20+5
expr 20+5
→ 20+5

# bc's result doesn't give the fractional part by default
bc <<< 9.0/2.0
→ 4

# expr does only integer
expr 9 / 2
→ 4

# same for POSIX arithmetic expansion
echo $((9/2))
→ 4

# bash arithmetic expansion chokes on floats
echo $((9.0/2.0))
→ bash: 9/2.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")

# Most `expr` implementations also have problems with floats
expr 9.0 / 2.0
→ expr: non-integer argument
```

A syntax error like the last ones is easily noticed, but integer responses with a discarded float part can easily go unnoticed and lead to wrong results.

That's why I always use a scripting language like Lua for that. But you can choose any scripting language that you're familiar with. I just use Lua as an example. The advantages are

- a familiar syntax
- familiar functions
- familiar caveats
- flexible input
- spaces usually don't matter
- floating point output

Examples:

```
lua -e "print(9/2)"
→ 4.5

lua -e "print(9 / 2)"
→ 4.5

lua -e "print(9.0/2)"
→ 4.5

lua -e "print (9 /2.)"
→ 4.5

lua -e "print(math.sqrt(9))"
→ 3
```

Comment: `bc`'s result is not integer, just rounded to `scale`, who's default value is 0. So `bc <<< 'scale=4;9.0/2.0'` if you want the fractional part.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But still, it's error prone. Will I remeber to add `scale` if I use `bc` in a couple of weeks? Probably not. And even if there's a way to change it permanently, it will bite you if you're on a system with the default settings.

Comment: Personally I do remember about `scale` since I met `bc` first time years ago. But I always forgot whether the output function in `lua` is `put` or `puts`. ;)

Comment: Just count bc as one of the scripting languages. I always know whether I need integer results or not - if integer is alright I stay in bash, else I rarely have reason to use bc. For lua, you have to remember -e, print and parenthesis.

Comment: Just always use `bc -l` rather than plain `bc`, then never worry about `scale`.

Comment: I don't like the emphasis on what other answers got wrong. When looking for answers I personally expect the answer first.

Comment: +1 on your critique of other methods, but lua, while useful, is still a bit on the heavy side and, more importantly, far from universally available.

Answer (score 20):

You could use `bc`. E.g.,

```
$ echo "25 + 5" | bc
30
```

Alternatively `bc <<< 25+5` will also work.

Or interactively, if you want to do more than just a single simple calculation:

```
$ bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
25 + 5
30
```

The GNU implementation of `bc` prints that header/copyright info on start-up when both its stdin and stdout go to a terminal. You can suppress it with the (GNU-specific) `-q` option. For more information see the [bc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc)

Comment: +1 for both pipe ("|") and interactive mode options for bs.  Does one `ctrl-d` to exit?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Yes, ^D will do the trick as will `quit`

Comment: `c ()
{
    bc -l <<< "$@"
}
` will define a function `c`  for quick and easy use. e.g. `c 3/2` will give you `1.50000000000000000000`.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `calc`:

If you just enter `calc` with no other arguments it enters an interactive mode where you can just keep doing math.  You exit this by typing exit:

```
C-style arbitrary precision calculator (version 2.12.3.3)
Calc is open software. For license details type:  help copyright
[Type "exit" to exit, or "help" for help.]

; 2+4
6
; 3+5
8
; 3.4+5
8.4
; 2^4
16
; exit
```

Or you use it with the expression as an argument and it will provide the answer and then exit

```
$calc 2 + 4
    6
$
```

`calc` is similar to `bc`, I just like the way it behave as default better

Answer (score 14):

I like to fire up Python and use it as an interactive calculator (but then again, I'm a Python programmer).

Comment: I always have one window in `screen` just running Python.

Comment: pythonpy (https://github.com/russell91/pythonpy) is a nice way to do this and other things in python syntax without having to fire up an interactive shell: py '3.2 * 5' => 16

Comment: I like python but it's start up time becomes important if you just want to add two numbers in a few places of your bash script

Comment: @ndemou I said "interactive" calculator. Although it's also worth noting that at some point if you are doing complex enough things in a script, sanity dictates you use something other than bash (like Python).

Answer (score 11):

Since no-one else has mentioned it, and though it's not strictly a calculator (but neither are all these general-purpose scripting languages), I'd like to mention `units`:

```
$ units "1 + 1"
        Definition: 2
$ units "1 lb" "kg"
        * 0.45359237
         / 2.2046226
```

Or, for less output so you can get just the number to use in `$()` to assign to something:

```
$ units -t "1 + 1"
2
$ units -t "1 lb" "kg"
0.4539237
```

And it even does temperature conversions

```
$ units -t "tempC(20)" "tempF"
68
```

To get the temperature conversion in an expression for further calculation, do this:

```
$ units -t "~tempF(tempC(20))+1"
68.1
```

Comment: There are so many options that don't require installing an extra program that I don't see why one would want to go that way.

Comment: @ndemou It's installed by default on some distributions... and a lot of these other answers aren't. And did you really need to comment that on an answer that's five years old?

Comment: I think it's good to comment when I down-vote and it is a practice that's also encouraged by S.E. I don't see why five years are relevant. The same comment applies to all similar answers -- nothing personal. (BTW even the most obscure program can be be installed by default on _some_ distribution. In this case I've tested recent installations of Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS and RedHat and units is not)

Answer (score 8):

```
$> ghc -e '20 + 5'
25
it :: Integer
```

---

Also `ghci`, that is the [*Glasgow-Haskell Compiler*](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/GHCi) in interactive mode (`ghc --interactive`, as opposed to it evaluating an expression with [`-e`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/modes.html)), makes for a fascinating "calculator":

```
$>ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> pi
3.141592653589793
Prelude> ceiling pi
4
Prelude> compare 1 2
LT
```

Answer (score 8):

### For Integer arithmetic (where 3/2=1)

- **`bash`** `echo $(( 1+1 ))`
- **`fish`** `math 1+1`
- **`zsh*`** `echo $((1+1))`

*: and ksh93, yash

### For floating point arithmetic (where 3/2=1.5)

- **`bash`** `awk "BEGIN {print 10/3}"` *(low precision)*
- **`bash`** `echo "10/3"|bc -l` *(high precision)*
- **`fish`** `math -s4 10/3`
- **`zsh*`** `echo $((10./3))`

*: and ksh93, yash

You can of course configure your shell to use awk with minimum typing like `calc 10/3` (see notes on how to do it for bash<sup>1</sup> and fish<sup>2</sup>).

The main reason for suggesting awk for bash is that it's preinstalled on almost all Unix-like OSes and is reasonably light (there is of course the cost of starting a process) with a less precise but more human-friendly output than `bc -l` which prints 20 decimal digits (although you can certainly [tweak awk to get more decimal digits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57006/awk-high-precision-arithmetic)).

---

### Notes

#### (1) How to use the simplified syntax in bash

Add this bash function to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
calc(){ awk "BEGIN { print $*}"; }
```

#### (2) How to use the simplified syntax in fish

Create a `calc` fish function (i.e. a text file named `/home/ndemou/.config/fish/functions/calc.fish`):

```
function calc
    awk "BEGIN{ print $argv }" ;
end
```

Comment: `awk` will use your system's `double` floating point type, so is going to be as _precise_ as most other tools that don't do arbitrary precision (note that gawk can do arbitrary precision). `awk` uses the `OFMT` variable to convert number to their string representation for output (`%.6g` by default, you may want to change that to `%.17g` is you want higher _precision_).

Comment: Note that `fish`'s `math` is just a function that calls `bc` (though [that's to change](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3157))

Comment: Well, it was a function that calls `bc`. It's not any longer in newer versions where things like `math "scale=4; 10/3"` won't work anymore (`math -s4 10/3` instead now)

Comment: Thanks Stéphane Chazelas -- I've updated my answer (`math -s4` seems to be supported in older versions also)

Answer (score 6):

### Gnuplot

[*gnuplot - an interactive plotting program*](http://www.gnuplot.info/)
Follow the above link or type `gnuplot` form the prompt then `help` inside the *gnuplot* interpreter.
*Gnuplot* is a program born to plot data, but can be used for calculation too. It offer the advantage that you can define functions and or use the built-in ones.

```
echo  "pr 20+5/2"  |  gnuplot          #  Lazy-note `pr` instead of print
22                                     #  Integer calculation & result
echo  "pr 20.+5/2"  |  gnuplot         #  Lazy-note `pr` instead of print
22.0                                   #  Floating point result
echo  "pr sin(2*pi/3.)"  |  gnuplot    #  Some functions ...
0.866025403784439
```

### Root (or some other *C interpreter*)

> *The [ROOT system](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) provides a set of OO frameworks with all the functionality needed to handle and analyze large amounts of data in a very efficient way...*

You can use it as *C interpreter*, [*CINT*](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint), or you can use one of the [many many other C interpreters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c) . IMHO, it's huge, complex, powerful, and not always friendly but can give big satisfaction too.

If you really do not want to listen the little voice inside you that cites [Confucio](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/never-use-a-cannon-to-kill-a-fly/365643.html) and you are ready [*to break a (butter)fly on the wheel*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/100220) you can use *root*. In this case `-l` is mandatory to avoid to show splash screen...

```
echo  "20+5/2"   | root -l
(const int)22
echo  "20+5/2."  | root -l
(const double)2.25000000000000000e+01

echo  "cout<< 20+5/2 << endl;"   | root -l
22
```

Answer (score 5):

For console calculations, I use `concalc`.  (`sudo aptitude install concalc`)

After that, just type `concalc`  and hit enter.  It won't supply a prompt, but just type in the your calculation (no spaces) and hit enter, and on the next line, it'll give you the numeric value.

Answer (score 5):

I can't believe to read "the power of JavaScript" (but I had to upvote the answer for the other parts, except perl of course.

Practically, for the simple cases where integer arithmetic is sufficient, I use the buildin $((...)) and recommend it. Else, in almost all cases echo "..." | bc is sufficient.

For some arithmetic operations like statistics, matrix operations and more `R` is the better tool:

```
echo 25 + 5 | R --vanilla
```

and for small datasets and graphical throw away results, `oocalc` is a nice utility.

Answer (score 5):

I use a little python script that will evaluate a python expression and print the result, then I can run something like

```
$ pc '[i ** 2 for i in range(10)]'
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

the script is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import sys
import traceback
from codeop import CommandCompiler

compile = CommandCompiler()
filename = "<input>"
source = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) + '\n'

try:
    code = compile(source, filename) 
except (OverflowError, SyntaxError, ValueError):
    type, value, sys.last_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    sys.last_type = type
    sys.last_value = value
    if filename and type is SyntaxError:
        # Work hard to stuff the correct filename in the exception
        try:
            msg, (dummy_filename, lineno, offset, line) = value.args
        except ValueError:
            # Not the format we expect; leave it alone
            pass
        else:
            # Stuff in the right filename
            value = SyntaxError(msg, (filename, lineno, offset, line))
            sys.last_value = value
    lines = traceback.format_exception_only(type, value)
    print(''.join(lines))
else:
    if code:
        exec(code)
    else:
        print('incomplete')
```

Unfortunately I don't remember where I borrowed most of the code from, so I can't cite it.

Comment: wouldn't `print(eval(' '.join(sys.argv[1:])))` do the same thing?

Comment: You're using a hammer to hit a fly here

Answer (score 4):

Use the [*GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library*](https://gmplib.org/) through the supplied `run-expr` program:

- Download and extract(you will need lzip): `tar -xvf gmp-5.1.3.tar.lz`
- In the top directory, `./configure` and `make` (no need to install)
- In demos/expr, `make run-expr`
- I like to create a symbolic link to it in my `~/bin` directory: `ln -s /path/to/gmp/demos/expr/run-expr ~/bin/run-expr`
- Add an alias for easy use; for instance `alias calcf='run-expr -f'` for floating point evaluation

Output:

```
# calcf '2/3'
"2/3" base 0: result 0.666666666666666666667e0
```

From the `run-expr.c` file:

```
Usage: ./run-expr [-z] [-q] [-f] [-p prec] [-b base] expression...

   Evaluate each argument as a simple expression.  By default this is in mpz
   integers, but -q selects mpq or -f selects mpf.  For mpf the float
   precision can be set with -p.  In all cases the input base can be set
   with -b, or the default is "0" meaning decimal with "0x" allowed.
```

See the [manual](https://gmplib.org/manual/Function-Classes.html#Function-Classes) for function classes differences and details.

Answer (score 3):

**SQLite**:

```
echo 'select 1 + 1;' | sqlite3
```

**MySQL**:

```
mysql -e 'select 1 + 1 from dual;'
```

**PostgreSQL**:

```
psql -c 'select 1 + 1 as sum;'
```

Comment: Some minor details worth to mention: 1) `from dual` is needed by Oracle, MySQL is able to `select` without `from` clause. 2) PostgreSQL not requires the alias. 3) The `;` is only required by SQLite. 4) MySQL and PostgreSQL will work only if they are able to connect to a database server. 5) MySQL and PostgreSQL will draw ASCII-art table around the results. To get only the value: `mysql -BNe 'select 1+1'` and `psql -tAc 'select 1+1`.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of solutions here all have notable drawbacks.

So I have created a new command to be able to do this in the simplest and most reliable way.

It's simply a wrapper around Perl, but by turning behavior predictable. With more flexible input, and actual crashing on unsolvable functions.

Samples:

```
$ solve 1/5
0.2

$ solve 1.5+3.1
4.6

$ solve 1/1000000
1e-06

$ solve 7+2^3
15

$ solve "sqrt(8)"
2.82842712474619

$ solve 1/0
non solvable : 1/0
```

- [Source code](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/solve)
- [Pacman repository](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/express-repository)