# Evaluating the return value of a command line

Tags: shell, exit, output

How do I evaluate or calculate the return value of a command line?
For exemple, I count the number of lines with a grep and I want to know if that value is above X. If so, I want to print the number to a file.

Or I want to substract the value of a grep count to another grep count...

How can I manipulate return values that way ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are mixing two things the return value typically indicates if a command was successful (return value 0) or not (anything else). You can get the return value of a command from the variable `$?`

grep -c returns the count to stdout, to capture the count you can use something like

```
variable=$(grep -c pattern filename)
```

Afterwords you can calculate/access the variable how ever you want. See [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-can-i-do-command-line-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-any-language) how to calculate stuff with the output.

Comment: Yeah that was what I meant. And your answer is perfect !

Comment: `$?` is the 8-bit exit status of each program. Values of `0` and `1` have standard definitions. Values `2` through `255` are reserved for the program - it may return more information, check the `man` page for the particular program. Some usages ignore this extra information, and treat `$?` value `0` as Success, anything else as Not-Success (Failure).