# Adding two numbers using expr

Tags: shell-script

I'm learning Shell scripting for a diploma in IT I'm currently doing. I'm trying to write a small script that adds two numbers as shown as in one of the tutorials we were given.

```
echo "Enter two numbers"
read num1 num2
sum = 'expr $num1 + $num2'
echo "The sum is = $sum"
```

However when I give it the execution permission and run the script, it gives me this error.

```
sum: =. No such file or directory.
sum: expr $num1 + $num2: No such file or directory
```

[image]

I tried running this on both Ubuntu and Fedora but same error occurs. Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-can-i-do-command-line-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-any-language

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First you have to get rid of the spaces for the assignment, e.g

```
sum='expr $num1 + $num2'
```

then you have to change `'` to a `` ` `` or even better to `$()`:

```
sum=$(expr "$num1" + "$num2")
```

instead of using `expr` you can also do the calculation directly in your shell:

```
sum=$((num1 + num2))
```

Comment: If the motivation for using `expr` instead of `$((...))` is a desire to be portable to classic Bourne shell, then it's a good idea to avoid `$(...)` as well.

Comment: @AlanCurry are there any shells not supporting `$()`? As far as i know it is required by posix, e.g. all posix compatible shells should support `$()`

Comment: @UlrichDangel The original Bourne shell didn't have `$(…)`, but it has about died out (maybe someone somewhere is still running `/bin/sh` on Solaris).

Comment: The C Shell doesn’t support `$(…)` –– or at least, not all versions.

Comment: What is the purpose of having double quotes around the variables?

Answer (score 9):

You have probably misread backticks as single quotes in the line:

```
sum = 'expr $num1 + $num2'
```

See [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) on using `$(...)` instead.

This works as expected:

```
sum=$(expr "$num1" + "$num2")
```

Also note there are no gaps around the equals sign (the variable assignment).

Answer (score 1):

`expr` is an external program used by **Bourne shell**(i.e. sh). Bourne shell didn't originally have any mechanism to perform simple arithmetic. It uses `expr` external program with the help of backtick.

The backtick(**`**) is actually called command substitution . Command substitution is the mechanism by which the shell performs a given set of commands and then substitutes their output in the place of the commands.

```
sum=`expr $num1 + $num2`
```

---

In **bash**(bourne again shell) it has the following systax, it won't use extrnal program `expr`.

```
sum=$((num1+num2))
```

if we want to use the external program `expr`. we have the following systax:

```
sum=$(expr $num1 + $num2)
```