# Calculate variable, and output it to another variable

Tags: shell, arithmetic, bc, calculator

The only calculator I know is `bc`. I want to add `1` to a variable, and output to another variable.

I got the `nextnum` variable from counting string in a file:

```
nextnum=`grep -o stringtocount file.tpl.php | wc -w`
```

Lets say the `nextnum` value is `1`. When added with `1`, it will become `2`. To calculate, I run:

```
rownum=`$nextnum+1 | bc`
```

but got error:

```
1+1: command not found
```

I just failed in calculation part. I've tried changing the backtick but still not works. I have no idea how to calculate variables and output it to another variable.

Comment: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-can-i-do-command-line-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-any-language

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The substring inside the `` ` ` `` must be a valid command itself:

```
rownum=`echo $nextnum+1 | bc`
```

But is preferable to use `$( )` instead of `` ` ` ``:

```
rownum=$(echo $nextnum+1 | bc)
```

But there is no need for `bc`, the shell is able to do *integer* arithmetic:

```
rownum=$((nextnum+1))
```

Or even simpler in `bash` and `ksh`:

```
((rownum=nextnum+1))
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use built in arithmetic in bash:

```
rownum=$((nextnum+1))
```

which would be slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely right and complete the suggested solutions, just to mention the way it has to be done in former times when only the Bourne-Shell was available, that's the way it likes it:

```
rownum=`expr $nextnum + 1`
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use (as was mentioned before) `rownum=$((nextnum+1))` or `((rownum=nextnum+1))` but if you prefer an standard command you can use the let command, like `let rownum=$nextnum+1`

Comment: Calling `let` a “standard command” is very misleading. `$((…))` is standard (POSIX) syntax whereas `let` is a ksh (and bash, zsh) extension.