# Shell scripting to divide numbers inside a file

Tags: shell-script, arithmetic

I have a single column and 12 rows. Each row has numerical values. I want to divide each row values by some constant number (say C) using shell (bash) scripting. How to do this ? 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 7):

```
martin@dogmeat ~ % cat test 
100
50
25
martin@dogmeat ~ % cat test | while read i; do echo "$i/2" | bc; done
50
25
12
martin@dogmeat ~ % cat test | while read i; do echo "scale = 5; $i/2.0" | bc; done
50.00000
25.00000
12.50000
```

`bc` doesn't have a rounding function, so if you want to have those numbers properly rounded you will probably have to implement the function yourself.

Comment: You can use `printf` to do the rounding for you

Comment: I would use `done < test` to avoid the UUoC.

Comment: the trouble with caring about UUoC is that in `cat` is often just a placeholder for any other command or pipeline that produces output.

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK with integer division:

```
c=3
while read num; do
    echo $(( num / c ))
done < file
```

otherwise, you can use

```
awk -v c=3 '{ print $1/c }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

To get around the intricacies of shell floating point arithmetic, why not use Perl?
Here's a one-liner to do it:

```
C=3 perl -ne 'printf "%.2f\n",$_/$ENV{C}' your_file
```

The gargantuan answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks) may also be interesting to you.