# Attempted assignment to non-variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

We can use arithmetic operations inside shell script function:

```
function mess
{
   if (( "$1" > 0 )) ; then
      total=$1
   else
      total=100
   fi
   tail -$total /var/adm/messages | more
}
```

I try to  do this arithmetic operations on the function args:

```
#!/bin/bash
byte="Bytes"
kilo="KB"
mega="MB"
giga="GB"
function bytesToUnites() {
if (( "$1" < 1000 )) 
then
    echo $1" "$byte
elif (( $1 < 1000000 ))
then
    let $1/=1000
    echo $1" "$kilo
fi
}

bytesToUnites 28888
```

But I get this error:

```
line 12: let: 28888/=1000: attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "/=1000")
28888 KB
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your placement of `"` characters is not optimal. In almost all cases, expansion of `$var` should be inside `"`, not outside of it. So for example `echo $1" "$byte` is bad, `echo "$1 $byte"` is good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to perform [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) by preceding the first positional parameter name with `$`.

You can accomplish what you want like so:

```
...
elif [ $1 -lt 1000000 ]
then
    arg="$1"
    let arg/=1000
    echo $arg" "$kilo
fi
```

As far as I can tell, you can't use the positional parameter directly by saying:

```
let 1/=1000
```

because this would be a syntax error.

Incidentally, from your error message, I can see that `$1` was set to `28888`. You should note that Bash doesn't do floating point arithmetic. You will find `arg` set to `28` (the quotient of integer division of 28888 by 1000) instead of 28.888. Please see [this wonderful Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks) on how to do floating point arithmetic in scripts.

Comment: Thanks I wanted to upvote it but I can't

Comment: @user79550 No worries. If the answer properly solves your problem, consider accepting it (click the tick button under the vote buttons) so that others know this question is solved.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to assign values to positional parameters in `bash` is via the `set` builtin:

```
set a b
```

assigns `a` to `$1` and `b` to `$2` (note that it resets the whole positional parameter list, so `$3`, `$4`... are lost).

So here, you could do:

```
set -- "$(($1 / 1000))"
```

To assign the value of `$1` divided by 1000 to `$1`.

By contrast, with `zsh` (a more advanced Bourne-like shell, not part of the GNU project, found on all Unices though often not by default), you can assign individual positional parameters like:

```
1=$(($1 / 1000))
```

Or:

```
argv[1]=$(($1 / 1000))
```

Or:

```
(( argv[1] /= 1000 ))
```

(`$argv` is a special array tied to the positional parameters there)

You still cannot do:

```
let 1/=1000
(( 1/=1000 ))
```

though.

`zsh` also supports floating point arithmetics, so you can do:

```
((argv[1] /= 1000.))
```

(the use a of a floating point constant (1000.) forces floating point arithmetic).

You may want to display it like:

```
printf "%.2f$kilo\n" $1
```

Comment: I have tried `printf "%.2f$kilo\n" $1` as you suggested but it printed `28.00` instead of `28.88` @Stéphane Chazelas

Comment: @user79550, in `zsh`? After `((argv[1] /= 1000.))` ?

Comment: Is  there other ways that I can get the floating point without `zsh`

Comment: @user79550, you can call any other application (shell or not) that can do floating point arithmetic from your dumb shell (zsh, ksh93, bc, dc, awk, perl, php... see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks)

Answer (score 0):

For my two cents, I'll recommend you use the `%` modulo. You can just walk up the unit list and save your remainder every step. Here:

```
(   
    gb=$(((mb=(kb=1024*(b=1))*kb)*kb))                 #define units 
    set -- 8934752983457                               #your $1 - just a random test
    for u in '' k m g                                  #this part is neat
    do  [ $((c=$1/${u}b)) -ge 1 ] || break             #math eval varnames
        [ "$u" != g ] && c=$(($c%$kb))                 #if not yet g only save %
        set -- $(($1-$c)) "$c${u}b${2:+.$2}"           #decrement $1 - build $2
    done ; shift                                       #done - toss $1
    IFS=. ; printf %s\\n $*                            #split $2 andd print
)
```

#### OUTPUT

```
8321gb
140mb
454kb
417b
```