# I want to divide a sum of numbers by a value

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

So here is my code for Unix shell scripting

```
#! /bin/ksh

echo "Enter your first number:"    
read first

echo "Enter your second number:"    
read second

echo "Enter your third number:"    
read third

SUM=`expr $first + $second + $third`    
AVERAGE="$SUM/3"

echo "The average is $AVERAGE"
```

Basically I want to find the average of the 3 values that a user enters. The result I get once I enter all of the values, for example all values add up to 12; is "The average is 12/3".

Comment: How is it that you knew you had to use `expr` to do the sums, but didn't realize you also needed it for the division?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks)

Answer (score 5):

slm's answer here hasn't taken into account that you asked about the Korn shell, not about the Bourne Again shell.  The (93) Korn shell has no built-in `expr` command, so when using `expr` in Korn shell scripts you are using an external `expr` command.  This is not a problem per se.  After all, it's how one did things with the Bourne shell, which also had no `expr` built-in command.  But as M. Kohen points out, one might prefer to use shell built-ins when a shell has them.  And the Korn shell has.

M. Kohen points to the *arithmetic substitution* available in the Korn shell.  It's important to remember that this *is* a substitution, so you must do something with the substituted result if you don't want to just run it as a command.  The more complete form of M. Kohen's answer (fixing the operator precedence error along the way) is thus:

```
AVERAGE="$(( (first + second + third) / 3))"
```

But there are two other ways of doing this in the Korn shell.  The Korn shell has a built-in command named `let` that does *arithmetic evaluation* on each of its arguments:

```
let "AVERAGE = (first + second + third) / 3"
```

Every argument to the command is a single expression, so whitespace needs to be quoted as here.

It also has a piece of syntax that is described in one ksh clone's manual as "syntactic sugar for `let`" with the expression turned into a single argument to that command:

```
(( AVERAGE = (first + second + third) / 3 ))
```

### Further reading

- *[KornShell 93 Manual Page](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html)*. 2012-06-19.  AT&T.
- Bill Rosenblatt and Arnold Robbins (April 2002).  "[6.2. Numeric Variables and Arithmetic](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch06_02.htm)".  *Learning the Korn Shell*.  O'Reilly.  2nd Edition. ISBN 0-596-00195-9

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I've added the tag and amended my A so that it's clear that it pertains to Bash and not Korn. If you see something egregiously wrong like this feel free to do a suggested edit on the Q to get it retagged and to leave the answered a comment alerting them to this. I only found this by accident.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in arithmetic support in the shell that is used by a double parenthesis preceded by a dollar sign:

`$(( (first + second + third) / 3))`

This is more efficient than `expr` since it does not require a separate process (and hence fork, exec, pipe management and return).

Answer (score 2):

Your question originally did not have the Korn Shell tag so I've since added it. If you were using Bash the following would apply.

---

The command `expr` can perform a variety of mathematical calculations. Simply make use of it to perform the averaging as well.

```
$ AVG=$(expr $SUM / 3)
```

Also you'll typically want to make use of this form of sub commands, `$(...cmd...)`, instead of backticks. So change your `SUM=` line to this instead:

```
SUM=$(expr $first + $second + $third)
```

If you're unsure what a particular command can do for you be sure to check out the man pages. The command `expr` has all the operations that it's able to carry out, `man expr`.

#### References

- [bash-hackers.org wiki - sub commands](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst)
- [Chapter 12. Command Substitution - Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)