# Rounding float numbers in csh

Tags: csh, arithmetic, floating-point

I have a float number stored in a variable $temp, like 3.046789. How we can round this number with 2 digits precision and the result I need is 3.05. The script I have is a csh script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command [`printf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/printf.1.html) to format numbers in lots of ways, just like with the C function `printf()`:

To make it independent of the shell used, run `/usr/bin/printf`

```
$ LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/printf '%.2f\n' 3.046789
3.05
```

The syntax of the format is described in the man page of the library function: [`man 3 printf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/printf.3.html).

Not sure about the variable handling in `csh`.

Additionally, `printf` can be available as a shell builtin command that does the same, like in bash.

Comment: @terdon It's more correct with the edit, but the idea for mentioning the builtins only at the end was that any builtin should do the same as `/usr/bin/printf`, because that is exceptionally well defined - does that make sense?

Comment: Absolutely, I just edited to clarify that `printf` is not always a builtin. I don't know if there is any flavor of printf that won't do what you describe in your answer, just that on systems running a sheel that has a builtin, that will be used before the separate binary. Admittedly, `csh`, does not seem to have the builtin so it makes no difference to the OP but other shells do.

Comment: @terdon Ah, now I see: I mentioned `/usr/bin/printf` directly before the command, explicitly implying that would use `/usr/bin/printf`, which is just wrong with a builtin - did not mean to have that implication. (btw, turns out `csh` does not have the builtin: (`$ csh -c builtins | grep -Fx printf`).

Comment: Now who wants to add this to the canonical question [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/80216) (@terdon?)

Comment: @G-Man Good idea, I'll do!