# bash + how to calculate very long numbers in bash?

Tags: bash, arithmetic

How to calculate very long numbers in bash?

```
param=$(( 3247238523785623478565 + 53453453252345346534563412634 ))

echo $param
3420247196502465471
```

as we see here, this isn't the right answer because of the limit of integer numbers.

Comment: [Take your pick](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/12779)

Comment: the link above "How do integer & float" does not say anything about long numbers in bash.   Most of the answers depend on tools other than bash (not always an option). so this is not a duplicate of that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `bc` ("an arbitrary precision calculator language"):

```
param=$(bc <<< '3247238523785623478565 + 53453453252345346534563412634')
```