# Copy Single Value from a file to a variable and perform arithmetic over it?

Tags: shell-script, files, variable, arithmetic, floating-point

Suppose we have a file like 'abc.txt' which has a single value `123456` and file 'xyz.txt' which also has a single value like `654321`. I want to store these values form the file to some shell variable like `abc = 123456` and `xyz = 654321` and wanted to do some operations like `density=$abc/$xyz`. I am able to transfer the contents form the file to variables but it is not treating contents of shell variables like numbers on which we can do arithmetic. What can be done for this?

[How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks) link has helped various ways to do arithmetic but did not tell about the values from the file assigned to variable will be eligible for arithmetic or not?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks

Comment: If you are "able to transfer the contents from the file to variables", why are you asking how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Bash shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
abc=$(<abc.txt)
xyz=$(<xyz.txt)
density=$((abc / xyz))
echo "$density"
```

Note: Output will be `0` for this because *numerator* is less than *denominator*.

Comment: @Fiximan: I know that, but OP wants in that way and thats why I mentioned like that.

Answer (score 0):

Shell arithmetics is integer only. Use `bc` for that:

```
echo $var1/$var2 | bc -l
```

or the simpler

```
bc -l <<< $var1/$var2
```

Comment: What should be done if we want floating point arithmetic to be done using shell variables. Please answer me, I am stuck in somewhere very critical issues.