# Subtract floating numbers in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ksh, arithmetic

I'm trying to do some calculation in shell script with CPU usage. Which return floating point number. But when I subtract this number I'm getting error. See the following code and error.

**Code**

```
#!/bin/sh

CPU_IDLE=98.67
echo $CPU_IDLE
CPU_USAGE=$(( 100 - $CPU_IDLE ))
echo $CPU_USAGE
```

**Error**

```
./poc.sh: line 14: 100 - 98.67 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".67 ")
```

Comment: see [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither `bash` nor `ksh` can perform floating point arithmetic (`ksh93` supports that if I remember correctly). I recommend to switch to `zsh` or run external tool like `bc`:

```
$ CPU_IDLE=98.67
$ echo "$CPU_IDLE"
$ CPU_USAGE=$( bc <<< "100 - $CPU_IDLE" )
$ echo "$CPU_USAGE"
1.33
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you used the [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) tag in your question, the script starts with the `#!/bin/sh` hashbang, which will *rarely* give you a korn shell.

The rest of the code works fine with `ksh` (AT&T ksh93) on ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ ksh poc.sh
98.67
1.33

$ ls -lL /bin/ksh*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1509040 Jan  9  2013 /bin/ksh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1509040 Jan  9  2013 /bin/ksh93
```

Comment: It will only work in locales where the decimal separator is the dot (`.`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas True. I guessed that a multi-locale solution was out-of-scope for this question.

Comment: Still worth pointing out as [it will affect most people in the non-english-speaking world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg).