# Bash multiplication and addition

Tags: bash, scripting, command-substitution

```
for k in {0..49};
do
a=$(($((2*$k))+1));
echo $a;
done
```

Hi, I need a simplified expression for the third line, maybe one that does not use command substitution.

Comment: @Theophrastus: As suggested  it works fine but what if i wanted to use expr instead of (()).

Comment: This is `bash` and not `C`, so remove all `;` - unless you write it in a singular line.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/117549

Comment: `declare -i a; for k in {0..49}; do a=2*$k+1; echo $a; done`

Comment: Aside: `$(( ... ))` is arithmetic expansion not command substitution.

Comment: The whole loop can be written `seq 1 2 99` or `printf '%s\n' {1..99..2}`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Using arithmetic expansion:

```
for (( k = 0; k < 50; ++k )); do
  a=$(( 2*k + 1 ))
  echo "$a"
done
```

Using the antiquated `expr` utility:

```
for (( k = 0; k < 50; ++k )); do
  a=$( expr 2 '*' "$k" + 1 )
  echo "$a"
done
```

Using `bc -l` (`-l` not actually needed in this case as no math functions are used):

```
for (( k = 0; k < 50; ++k )); do
  a=$( bc -l <<<"2*$k + 1" )
  echo "$a"
done
```

Using `bc -l` as a co-process (it acts like a sort of computation service in the background¹):

```
coproc bc -l

for (( k = 0; k < 50; ++k )); do
  printf "2*%d + 1\n" "$k" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read -u "${COPROC[0]}" a
  echo "$a"
done

kill "$COPROC_PID"
```

That last one looks (arguably) cleaner in `ksh93`:

```
bc -l |&
bc_pid="$!"

for (( k = 0; k < 50; ++k )); do
  print -p "2*$k + 1"
  read -p a
  print "$a"
done

kill "$bc_pid"
```

---

¹ This solved a an issue for me once where I needed to process a large amount of input in a loop. The processing required some floating point computations, but spawning `bc` a few times in the loop proved to be exceedingly slow. Yes, I could have solved it in many other ways, but I was bored...

Answer (score 26):

You can simplify:

```
a=$(($((2*$k))+1));
```

to:

```
a=$((2*k+1))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `let` command to force a calculation.

```
let a="2*k+1"
```

Note that we don't need `$k` in this structure; a simple `k` will do the job.

Comment: That fails if there's a file called `a=2whateverk+1` in the current directory. Worse, if there's a file called `a=2+b[$(reboot)]k+1`, that calls the `reboot` command. Best is to use `((...))` here (`((a = 2 * k + 1))`), or the POSIX syntax: `a=$((2 * k + 1))`

Comment: We can quote it; `let a="2*k+1"` to solve that.

Answer (score 4):

The arithmetic expansion you probably need is this:

```
a=$(( 1+2*k ))
```

In fact, you do not need to use a variable:

```
for k in {0..49}; do
    echo "$(( 1 + 2*k ))"
done
```

Or the counting variable could be moved to a `for ((…))` loop:

```
for (( k=0;k<50;k++ )); do
    a=$(( 1+2*k ))
    printf '%s\n' "$a"
done
```

#### for ((…)) loop

And, in that case, the arithmetic expansion could also be moved to inside the for loop:

```
for (( k=0 ; a=1+2*k , k<50 ;  k++)); do
    printf '%s\n' "$a"
done
```

Or, to get all values in an array:

```
for (( k=0 ; a[k]=1+2*k , k<49 ;  k++ )); do :; done
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"
```

#### No formula

But probably the shortest way to avoid any arithmetic expansion is to increment a variable twice:

```
for (( k=0,a=1 ; k<50 ;  k++,a++,a++ )); do
    printf '%s\n' "$a"
done
```

Or, even simpler, just use seq:

```
seq 1 2 100
```