# How to make $((5/2)) deliver a floating point number?

Tags: command-line, arithmetic

This is what I get

```
 echo $((5/2))
2
```

How to make $((5/2)) giving me 2.5 ?

Comment: `bc -l <<< 'scale=2; 5/2'`

Comment: your $PS1 is quite funny. any way you need to use another shell like [ksh93, yash or zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/44425), or use another tool for the maths

Comment: `$((5/2)).$((10*5/2%10))` (j/k)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc it is unicode, so any shell supporting unicode will work. That is all of them, though some struggle with non-ascii, when calculating widths. However you may need to install a new font, maybe a different terminal emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Bash will only work with integers. For more precision, use something like bc.