# Prepending each line with how long it took to generate it

Tags: shell, timestamps

I would like to have a script that would prepend each line of a stdin with information how long it took to generate it.
Basically for input:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

I would like to have

```
0 foo
10 bar
5 baz
```

Where 10 is 10 seconds passed between printing foo and printing bar, similar for 5, it took 5 seconds after printing bar to print baz.

I know there is a utility `ts` that shows timestamps and I know about https://github.com/paypal/gnomon, but I would prefer not to use javascript to do that.

Is there a standard tool for that or should I use awk and do processing?

Comment: The `time` command does this but I'm not quite sure how to extract it's output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's suppose that the script generating the output is called `generate`.  Then, to display the number of seconds it takes for it to generate each line:

```
$ generate | ( t0=$(date +%s); while read -r line; do t1=$(date +%s); echo " $((t1-t0)) $line"; t0=$t1; done )
 2 foo
 0 foo
 5 foo
 3 foo
```

The same commands spread out over multiple lines looks like:

```
generate | ( t0=$(date +%s)
    while read -r line
    do
        t1=$(date +%s)
        echo " $((t1-t0)) $line"
        t0=$t1
    done
    )
```

Alternatively, for convenience, we can define a shell function that contains this code:

```
timer() { t0=$(date +%s); while read -r line; do t1=$(date +%s); echo " $((t1-t0)) $line"; t0=$t1; done; }
```

We can use this function as follows:

```
$ generate | timer
 0 foo
 2 foo
 4 foo
 3 foo
```

#### How it works

- `t0=$(date +%s)`

  This captures the current time at the start of the script in seconds-since-epoch.
- `while read -r line; do`

  This starts a loop which reads from standard input
- `t1=$(date +%s)`

  This captures the time in seconds-since-epoch at which the current line was captured.
- `echo " $((t1-t0)) $line"`

  This prints out the time in seconds that it took for the current line.
- `t0=$t1`

  This updates `t0` for the next line.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
trickle () {
    awk 'BEGIN { t = systime(); OFS="\t" }
               { print systime() - t, $0 }
               { t = systime()           }'
}
```

This little shell function simply wraps an `awk` script (compatible with both GNU `awk`, and `mawk -Wi`, but not with BSD `awk` due to it missing `systime()`). It will output each line of input prefixed with the number of whole seconds since the last line of output. The first line will be prefixed with a zero.

Testing:

```
$ { echo hello; sleep 2; echo world } | trickle
0       hello
2       world
```

The `awk` script could obviously be run stand-alone as well:

```
$ some_command | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";t=systime()}{print systime()-t,$0;t=systime()}
```

E.g.

```
$ { echo hello; sleep 2; echo world; } | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";t=systime()}{print systime()-t,$0;t=systime()}'
0       hello
2       world
```

Comment: (note that it's @ThomasDickey's `mawk`, not the old one on Debian or derivatives).

Answer (score 3):

Well, [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) `ts` seems to be a perfect tool for that:

### for seconds since the start:

```
$ seq 5 | pv -qL 1 | ts -s %s
2 1
4 2
6 3
8 4
10 5
```

Or with more precision:

```
$ seq 5 | pv -qL 1 | ts -s %.s
1.949228 1
3.933483 2
5.917923 3
7.902231 4
9.886618 5
```

Or with `zsh` or `ksh93` (`$SECONDS` is integer by default but you can make it float with `typeset -F`; `pdksh` and `bash` have `$SECONDS` as well, but integer only):

```
$ typeset -F SECONDS=0; seq 5 | pv -qL 1 | while IFS= read -r line; do
   printf '%.3f %s\n' "$SECONDS" "$line"; done
1.987 1
3.972 2
5.956 3
7.941 4
9.925 5
```

### for seconds between lines

```
$ seq 5 | pv -qL 1 | ts -i %.s
1.947814 1
1.984442 2
1.984456 3
1.984151 4
1.984195 5
```

`zsh`/`ksh93`:

```
$ typeset -F SECONDS; seq 5 | pv -qL 1 | while SECONDS=0; IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%.6f %s\n' "$SECONDS" "$line"; done
1.985298 1
1.984322 2
1.984212 3
1.984240 4
1.984441 5
```

Comment: Where's `ts` from? GNU `moreutils`?

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, `moreutils` (not GNU's though). Note that the OP mentions it in his question.

Comment: `ts -i` is what I was looking for

Comment: On centos 7 `moreutils` package, `ts -i "%.s"` provides relative times, with sub-second values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`time`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/time.1.html) (note: a separate binary, not the shell built-in) and combine it with a while loop. To get the execution time for each command:

```
while read -r line; do
    /usr/bin/time -f "%e %C" $line 2>&1
done
```

Example output:

```
0.1 sleep 0.1
0.2 sleep 0.2
1.0 sleep 1
```

In case you want the total execution time from the beginning, you need to sum the execution time for each step. Precision for `%e` format is 1/100th of second, so you can't use [shell integer arithmetic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787/239817) directly (depending on the shell you using).

```
total=0.0

while read -r line; do
    t=$(/usr/bin/time -f "%e" $line 2>&1)
    total=$(awk "BEGIN{print $total+$t}")
    echo "$total $line"
done
```

Example output:

```
0.1 sleep 0.1
0.3 sleep 0.2
1.3 sleep 1
```

Comment: It doesn't look correct, I want o have information how long it took to generate the line, not a time from the beginning. In your case it should be `0.2 sleep 0.2    0.2 sleep 0.2     1.0 sleep 1`

Comment: I've edited the answer, the first example works as you described.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a simple function leveraging the bash builtin `SECONDS`. Notice we initialize it to zero on each invocation.

```
_time() { SECONDS=0; out="$($@)"; echo "[${SECONDS}] ${out:-no output}"; }
```

Next, use this `_time` function to run your command(s) from a list of commands could be a file of them, or whatever.

```
while read cmd; do _time $cmd; done < <(echo -e "sleep 5\nsleep 2\nsleep 1")
```

Here, sleep has no output, but your commands likely will. This is simply to show the use of SECONDS as it pertains to this problem. This example will output the default output of `no output`:

```
[5] no output
[2] no output
[1] no output
```