# how to get n-1 number

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing

I have a text file where I am keeping versions:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

and so on.

I need a way to give, for example, `4.0` as an input and get`3.0` as the output. Note that there would be thousands of versions.

I mean I want to give a version number and get the number of the previous version. So if I give `9.0`, I would get `8.0`.

I tried

```
  sed '1!G;h;$!d' test.txt
```

But this is printing all the numbers.

Comment: is there always will be strict order of lines/numbers? Do you just need to get the **previous** line?

Comment: What @RomanPerekhrest said. Also, can you have things like `4.2.1`? Will the version numbers always be foo dot bar (e.g. `2.3`) or can they be more complex? Will the file always be sorted?

Comment: not previous line.. i want n-1 number.. example.. if i enter 10.0 then output will 9.0.. sorting also i need to maintain.

Comment: @user2995458 OK, then please [edit] your question and clarify. But we also need to know if you want the previous version or just the -1. For example, if you have versions `1.0`, `1.2`, `2.0` and give `2.0` as input, do you want `1.0` or `1.2` as output? And what if you have `1.0.1`?

Comment: if you just want to subtract `1` from input numeric string, then, what's the point of using a file at all? Untill you elaborated, using a file is pointless

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest--yes my version will be like  4.0 and i want 3.0... there are no complexity in major.minor versions. actually i am maintaing versions in file.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Regarding questions like this, is there a consensus on this site (or on StackExchange in general) about whether or not questions should be answered as asked? I share your view that it seems unclear what the real purpose of this question is, but it isn't unintelligible.

Comment: @igal, no one told that it's *unintelligible*. I'm calling this pointless, cause you don't need a file for just inputting `4.0` to get `3.0`

Comment: @don_crissti, closing this is more intelligible. Done the same

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I didn't say that anyone told me that it's unintelligible. I asked whether or not there's a consensus about how to respond to "pointless" questions.

Comment: @igal, imho, I wouldn't recommend to answer pointless questions

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/117549

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks)

Comment: @igal - not only is this question poorly written, it is _definitely unclear_: there is no mention that "_they wanted to print the new list obtained by subtracting 1 from each number"_ as you say... That's _your interpretation_. If this question is about subtracting 1 from an integer then it should be closed as a duplicate so _either way_, it should be closed.

Comment: I agree with don_crissti: I read the question as “Given a file ***F*** and a number ***N**,* I want to compute ***N-1**.*”  I don’t see anything to support @igal’s interpretation that the OP wants to create file ***F₋₁**.*

Comment: @G-Man The example command was the clue. They said that they have their data in a text file. They showed a list of examples to illustrate the contents of the file. And then they gave a single `sed` command taking that file as input - that was their solution attempt.

Comment: @G-Man I feel like I'm getting sort of pushed into a position where it looks like I'm endorsing the way this question was written so, just to be clear, I think this question was written poorly. All I'm saying is that (apparently) I was able to figure out what they wanted without too much effort and also that it wouldn't take very much work to improve the statement of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with `bc` (see the [GNU bc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html)). You can pass `bc` an arithmetical expression and `bc` will evaluate it and return the result, e.g.

```
echo '9.0 - 1' | bc -l
```

This command returns `8.0` as its result.

Now suppose your version number is contained in the file `version.txt`, e.g.:

```bsh
echo '9.0' > version.txt
```

Then you could run the following command:

```bsh
echo "$(cat version.txt) - 1" | bc -l
```

This would produce `8.0` as its output. Alternatively, suppose that you have a list of version numbers in a file called `versions.txt` e.g.:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
10.0
```

We could create such a file like so:

```bsh
for i in {1..10}; do echo "${i}.0" >> versions.txt; done
```

In this case we could use `bc` inside of a while-loop:

```bsh
while read line; do echo "${line}-1" | bc -l; done < versions.txt
```

This produces the following output:

```bsh
0
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
```

Alternatively, you could extract the integer part from the version number and use `bash` to perform the arithmetic. You could use any number of text-processing tools to do this (e.g. `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etc.). Here is an example using the `cut` command:

```bsh
echo "$(( $(echo '9.0' | cut -d. -f1) - 1)).0"
```

This produces `8.0` as its output. Putting this into a while-loop gives us the following:

```bsh
while read line; do \
    echo "$(( $(echo ${line} | cut -d. -f1) - 1)).0";
done < versions.txt
```

Comment: hi Igal, in my system bc: command not found. do i have any alternate way?

Comment: @user2995458 please edit your question and tell us what operating system you use. Also clarify if your versions will always be this simple or if you can have sub versions (4.2.3 etc).

Comment: @user2995458 I've updated my solution to use a different command. But if you're frequently going to be doing arithmetic at the command-line then it might be worth installing `bc` anyway.