# Using a loop to generate command line arguments

Tags: bash, command-line, c

I am attempting to use a for loop to run command line arguments, I have never attempted this and I am having some trouble.

I am using the following commands:

```
for((a=1; a<20; a++)); 
do 
    ./a.out -N 10000 -D .25*a -E 0.7788007831;
done
```

I am using the getopt function in c to read in values. I want to try different values of D (called Delta in the output). However when I run this command I get:

```
Acceptance rate is: 0.928400
Estimate is:        0.758704
Error is :          0.020097
Delta used:         0.250000

Acceptance rate is: 0.928400
Estimate is:        0.758704
Error is :          0.020097
Delta used:         0.250000

Acceptance rate is: 0.928400
Estimate is:        0.758704
Error is :          0.020097
Delta used:         0.250000

Acceptance rate is: 0.928400
Estimate is:        0.758704 
Error is :          0.020097
Delta used:         0.250000

...

Acceptance rate is: 0.928400
Estimate is:        0.758704
Error is :          0.020097
Delta used:         0.250000
```

I'm not sure what the problem is though.

Comment: how is the shell supposed to know how to multiply that `.25*a` versus turning it into a glob or ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, if you want to refer to a shell variable, you need to use the `$foo` notation. `a` is just the letter "a" (in the same way `10000` is just the five digits), but `$a` expands to whatever the variable contains at the time.

Two, to do arithmetic in the shell, [the syntax for arithmetic expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) is  `$(( expression ))`, so you could write `$(( 25 * $a ))` to get the value of `a` times 25. (as a base 10 number.)

Though the problem you would face here, is that Bash (and the POSIX shell) can only do arithmetic on integers, so multiplying with `0.25` isn't going to work.

In zsh, the floating point arithmetic works, so you could do e.g.

```
for ((a=1; a<20; a++)); do 
    echo $((.25 * $a))
done
```

But in Bash or standard shell, you'll need to use an external program to do the maths:

```
for ((a=1; a<20; a++)); do 
    echo $( echo ".25 * $a" | bc -l )
done
```

Or in your command:

```
for ((a=1; a<20; a++)); do 
    ./a.out -N 10000 -D $( echo ".25 * $a" | bc -l ) -E 0.7788007831;
done
```

Of course, if the program you're running can do the multiplication and you just want to pass the strings `.25*1`, `.25*2` etc to it, then you'd use

```
... -D ".25*$a"
```

*with the quotes around it*, since otherwise the `*` is taken as a [filename match (glob)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob). (Actually you'll usually want to put quotes around most places where you use variable expansions or command substitutions, but let's just refer to [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373) on that.)

There's a number of ways for doing floating point math in the shell presented here: [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/170373)