# How to incorporate count add and sum

Tags: bash, shell-script

This is what I have so far. How could I incorporate count to take the user input each time the loop completes and add them together and create and average of the inputs?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Variables
lower=1
middle=50
higher=100
notdone=true

while [ $notdone ]; do

#Pick a Number
echo "Please pick a number between 1 and 100: "
read input


#Loop until wiithin range
until [[ $input -ge $lower ]] && [[ $input -le $higher ]]; do
    echo "Number not in range. 
    Please pick a number between 1 and 100: "
    read input
done

echo "You picked $input"

if [[ $input -ge $middle ]]; then 
    echo "Your answer is in the top half"
    fi

if [[ $input -le $middle ]]; then
    echo "Your answer is in the top half"
    fi
done
```

Comment: So I’ve since added count=0 as a variable within the while loop and at the end I’m trying to add something along the lines of total=$(expr “$count” + “$input”). But I can’t seem to figure out how to update the count variable with the user input from the previous run through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to your comment to the question: You don't need `$count` until actually computing the average.  Until then, it's enough to have

```
total=$(( total + input ))
```

This will add what the user inputted to the running total.

The average could then be calculated as `$(( total / count ))` (note, since the shell only does integer arithmetics, this would be an integer, see "[How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks)").

---

Other things:

Your `$notdone` variable is set to the *string* `true` and you use it in `while [ $notdone ]`.  Tests like these, on unquoted strings, are fragile, and your `while` loop condition is better written as

```
while [ "$notdone" = "true" ]
```

You should also consider quoting all other variable expansions in your code, for example

```
if [[ "$input" -ge "$middle" ]]; then
```

This is extra important in your  input loop, otherwise you'll generate a syntax error by inputting something with a space in the middle.

Since you are using `bash`, the above may also be written

```
if (( input >= middle )); then
```

You also lack a way of exiting your main loop, and both `echo`'s at the end says "Your answer is in the **top** half".