# AIX Does not support bc boolean expression

Tags: aix, bc

I ran into an issue where bc does not have boolean expressions in the AIX system. Wondering if there is a replacement command so I don't have make my code any longer? This is in a bash script.

Here is what I had:

```
percent=-0.17
max=0.20
if [[ $(bc <<< "$percent <= $max && $percent >= -$max") -ge 1 ]]; then
    echo "Under the $max acceptable buffer: File ACCEPTED" 
else
    echo "Over the $max acceptable buffer: File REJECTED"
    exit 1
fi
```

This is my output:

```
++ bc
syntax error on line 1 stdin
+ [[ '' -ge 1 ]]
```

Comment: You could use perl or awk

Comment: How can I use that in my scrip?

Comment: Maybe look into `man awk`?

Comment: Just curious, what would break if your code was a few bytes longer?

Comment: I’m comparing file size differences. We know how many bytes one line takes. So if there is too many lines in a file or too few we want to review that

Comment: @JeffSchaller for the link you provide. Would it still work if it’s a bash shell? Sorry I’m a bit new to scripting.

Comment: many shells won't do floating point math, so `awk` is the usual answer here

Comment: I ended up using `awk`. It just gave me more control over the range. This was from @JeffSchaller link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bc`'s POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html) does not require bare conditionals, and AIX's `bc` does not support them. You would have to break out the test like this:

```
percent=-0.17
max=0.20
if [[ $(bc <<< "if ($percent <= $max) if ($percent >= -$max) 1") -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "Under the $max acceptable buffer: File ACCEPTED" 
else
    echo "Over the $max acceptable buffer: File REJECTED"
    exit 1
fi
```

Re-formatting the `bc` script, it looks like this:

```
if ($percent <= $max) 
  if ($percent >= -$max) 
    1
```

... only if the $percent value is within *both* ranges does the expression `1` get executed, which prints `1` to stdout.

Comment: I see what you did here. But if floats are working in the `if statements` this should work by just comparing the two numbers directly?

Comment: @Tags, bash arithmetic is integer-only at this point; ksh93 supports floating point. See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks. So you need to be careful with the shell, or use a utility that supports it.

Comment: I see. Thanks and this works perfectly. I just didnt like that a `null` is passed but that was an easy modification