# How to check if integer value is less or more then 3

Tags: bash, awk, variable, numeric-data

We have two values

```
$a
$b
```

we need to compare the $a value with  $b value

in case $b value is less than ($a - 3) or more than ($a + 3), then it will print fail.

example:

```
a=10
b=14
```

then it should fail.

For:

```
a=10
b=11
```

then it's ok.

For:

```
a=23
b=6
```

then it should fail.

Comment: You applied the `awk` tag. Do you want your solution in awk or will plain bash do?

Comment: what you think its the best , depend to you ( even perl one liner )

Comment: What about `help -m test | less`?

Comment: *"in case $b value is less then 3 or more then 3 then it will print fail"* so it should only pass if $b is exactly 3? where does the value of $a come in to the calculation?

Comment: "The absolute value of their difference must be less than 3"?

Comment: ["There are lots of options"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/117549)

Comment: Is your question (and this is a guess): ”How can I tell if the, numeric, values of two variable differ by more than three?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite work out what exact numerical comparison you want to make, but in general in Bash arithmetic can be done as follows:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
a=100;
b=200;
threshold=50;

if [ $(($b - $a)) -gt $threshold ]
then
   echo Something.
else
   echo Something else.
fi
```

Comment: but what in case b is less then a ?

Answer (score 0):

Use bash arithmetic:

```
if (( (a-b) > 3 )) || (( (b-a) > 3 )); then
  echo fail
fi
```

Based on @ctrl-alt-delor's guess.