# How to divide numbers and return as float in #!/bin/sh

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing

Hi I have to divide two numbers in `#!/bin/sh`

```
$x = 5678
$x/1000
```

but calculations return only integer: `5`.

I need `5,678`.

I've tried

```
$x/1000.0 
$x/1000.0 | bc
```

on first method expect integer

second method: I don't have `bc`.

Comment: What system are you on that does not have `bc` installed by default?

Comment: Related/duplicate [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks)

Comment: @Kusalananda, some embedded system with e.g. Busybox? It appears to have an implementation of `bc`, since last December (version 1.30.0), but it might not be compiled in, or it might be an older version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
x=5678 y=1000
awk -- 'BEGIN{printf "%.3f\n", ARGV[1]/ARGV[2]}' "$x" "$y"
```

Whether you'll get `5.678` or `5,678` will depend on the locale (`$LC_ALL`, `$LC_NUMERIC`, `$LANG` variables) and the implementation of `awk` (some of which will use `.` regardless of the locale).

With the GNU implementation of `awk`, you need to pass a `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable into its environment for it to honour the locale for the decimal radix character.

That also applies to input numbers:

```
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 gawk -- 'BEGIN{
   printf "%.3f\n", ARGV[1]/ARGV[2]}' 1,2 10
0,120
```

```
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 gawk -- 'BEGIN{
   printf "%.3f\n", ARGV[1]/ARGV[2]}' 1.2 10
0,100
```

(in that latter case, the `1.2` was interpreted as `1`, because when doing an explicit conversion of string to number (like when using the `/` arithmetic operator here), `awk` parses as much of the string as it can as long as it makes a valid number and ignores the rest. That `.2` is not understood in that French locale as the decimal radix is `,` there, not `.`).

The `--`, to mark the end of options is needed in the busybox implementation of `awk` which you seem to be using as it accepts options after non-option arguments, which makes it non-POSIX compliant. Without it, the above wouldn't work if `$x` or `$y` were negative number.

Alternatvely, you could again set `$POSIXLY_CORRECT`, which would force it to parse its options the standard way. Note that in any case, busybox `awk` always uses `.` as the decimal radix character regardless of the locale and regardless of `$POSIXLY_CORRECT`.

Comment: works fine thanks

Comment: so but I have small problem when I want divide negitve number I get
awk: invalid option -- '1'
example -1234/1000

awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.3f\n", (-1234)/(1000)}' "$x" "$y"
works ok don't using varibales

Comment: @user22090909, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following `dc` snippet to get the result:

```
$ dc -e "3k $x 1000/p"
```

Comment: `echo "3k $x 1000/p" | dc` would be more portable. `-e` is not a standard option. Note negative numbers have to be entered as `_12345` instead of `-12345` and the decimal radix is going to be `.` regardless of the locale.