# How can I evaluate a math equation, one per line in a file?

Tags: bash, scripting, bc

I have a file with the following:

```
37 * 60 + 55.52
34 * 60 + 51.75
36 * 60 + 2.88
36 * 60 + 14.94
36 * 60 + 18.82
36 * 60 + 8.37
37 * 60 + 48.71
36 * 60 + 34.17
37 * 60 + 42.52
37 * 60 + 51.55
35 * 60 + 34.76
34 * 60 + 18.90
33 * 60 + 49.63
34 * 60 + 37.73
36 * 60 + 4.49
```

I need to write a shell command or Bash script that, for each line in this file, evaluates the equation and prints the result. For example, for line one I expect to see `2275.52` printed. Each result should print once per line.

I've tried `cat math.txt | xargs -n1 expr`, but this doesn't work. It also seems like `awk` might be able to do this, but I'm unfamiliar with that command's syntax, so I don't know what it would be.

Comment: I neglected to mention this but I'm using MinGW on Windows, and I don't have a `bc` command. I figured just basic shell utilities would get it done but I guess not?

Comment: Do you have  `awk`?

Comment: @void.pointer: `bc` **is** a "basic shell utility"

Comment: http://www.softndesign.org/blog/stubs/ccb.php/2017/03/24/minimal-bc-for-mingw

Comment: MinGW for Windows: http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: @guillermochamorro Yes I have `awk`. @jesse_b I assumed that to get `bc` I'd have to use a package manager, which I don't have in this version of mingw, so to me "basic" means what is included already. Sorry, it ended up being a rather ambiguous and useless statement.

Comment: @void.pointer MINGW should ship with `bc` because it claims to be POSIX compliant and POSIX requires the environment provide `bc`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This `awk` seems to do the trick:

```
while IFS= read i; do 
  awk "BEGIN { print ($i) }"
done < math.txt
```

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40897/338177)

Note that we're using `($i)` instead of `$i` to avoid problems with arithmetic expressions like `1 > 2` (`print 1 > 2` would print `1` into a file called `2`, while `print (1 > 2)` prints `0`, the result of that arithmetic expression).

Note that since the expansion of the `$i` shell variable ends up being interpreted as *code* by `awk`, that's essentially a *code injection vulnerability*. If you can't guarantee the file only contains valid arithmetic expressions, you'd want to put some input validation in place. For instance, if the file had a `system("rm -rf ~")` line, that could have dramatic consequences.

Comment: +1 This is probably the only case where using a shell variable in awk directly is correct, rather that using the `-v` option.

Answer (score 9):

here is what I whould do not sure it is the best method

```
bc < toto
```

depending what you want to do with datas

```
francois@zaphod:~$ cat > toto
37 * 60 + 55.52
34 * 60 + 51.75
36 * 60 + 2.88
36 * 60 + 14.94
36 * 60 + 18.82
36 * 60 + 8.37
37 * 60 + 48.71
36 * 60 + 34.17
37 * 60 + 42.52
37 * 60 + 51.55
35 * 60 + 34.76
34 * 60 + 18.90
33 * 60 + 49.63
34 * 60 + 37.73
36 * 60 + 4.49
francois@zaphod:~$ while read ; do echo " $REPLY" | bc  ; done < toto
2275.52
2091.75
2162.88
2174.94
2178.82
2168.37
2268.71
2194.17
2262.52
2271.55
2134.76
2058.90
2029.63
2077.73
2164.49
francois@zaphod:~$
```

without BC command you cannot use decimal values :

```
francois@zaphod:~$ while read ; do echo $(( "REPLY" )) ; done < toto
-bash: 37 * 60 + 55.52: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".52")
francois@zaphod:~$
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have perl:

```
perl -ne 'print eval $_,"\n"' math.txt
```

(I get 50000 lines per second on my laptop using this).

Comment: ok then :      perl -pe 's/(.*)/eval $1/e' file

Answer (score 4):

With *old-good* Python:

```
$ python -c $'import sys;\nfor line in sys.stdin:print(eval(line))' <math.txt
2275.52
2091.75
2162.88
2174.94
2178.82
2168.37
2268.71
2194.17
2262.52
2271.55
2134.76
2058.9
2029.63
2077.73
2164.49
```

Answer (score 3):

directly in bash/ksh (***Edit:*** As it turns out, `bash` can't do this, only `ksh` - thanks for pointing this out):

```
$ while read l
> do
> echo $(($l))
> done <<!
> 37 * 60 + 55.52
> 34 * 60 + 51.75
> 36 * 60 + 2.88
> 36 * 60 + 14.94
> 36 * 60 + 18.82
> 36 * 60 + 8.37
> 37 * 60 + 48.71
> 36 * 60 + 34.17
> 37 * 60 + 42.52
> 37 * 60 + 51.55
> 35 * 60 + 34.76
> 34 * 60 + 18.90
> 33 * 60 + 49.63
> 34 * 60 + 37.73
> 36 * 60 + 4.49
> !
2275.52
2091.75
2162.88
2174.94
2178.82
2168.37
2268.71
2194.17
2262.52
2271.55
2134.76
2058.9
2029.63
2077.73
2164.49
```

This may require a fairly recent version of your shell - `$((...))` used to only do integer arithmetics.

Comment: `bash` does **not** support floating point arithmetics.

Comment: Yeah what shell are you using that can do this?

Comment: Interesting - I have to admit, I hardly ever use `bash`, I prefer `ksh`, but that was for other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the results, I'd got with the answer provided by [@francois-p](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553423/364705)

For fun and games, add `paste` and `sed`:

```bash
$ paste <(sed 's/\($\)/\1\t=/g' somefile) <(bc < somefile)
37 * 60 + 55.52 =   2275.52
34 * 60 + 51.75 =   2091.75
36 * 60 + 2.88  =   2162.88
36 * 60 + 14.94 =   2174.94
36 * 60 + 18.82 =   2178.82
36 * 60 + 8.37  =   2168.37
37 * 60 + 48.71 =   2268.71
36 * 60 + 34.17 =   2194.17
37 * 60 + 42.52 =   2262.52
37 * 60 + 51.55 =   2271.55
35 * 60 + 34.76 =   2134.76
34 * 60 + 18.90 =   2058.90
33 * 60 + 49.63 =   2029.63
34 * 60 + 37.73 =   2077.73
36 * 60 + 4.49  =   2164.49
```

Answer (score 3):

With Perl:

```
perl -ple '$_=eval' ex
perl -nE 'say eval' ex
```

with Python:

```
python3 -qi < ex
python3 -qic 'import sys; sys.ps1=""' < ex
```

With Haskell:

```
ghci < ex
ghci < ex | grep -Po '> \S+$'
```

With calc:

```
calc -f ex      # apt install apcalc if necessary
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`/`python`:

```
python -c "$(awk '{printf "print %s;", $0}' math.txt)"
```

`awk` is being used here to format your file into an input that python will accept, then python is doing the work.

Alternatively `perl` can be used in pretty much the same way:

```
perl -le "$(awk '{printf "print %s;", $0}' math.txt)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Directly with `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf "%f\n", $0 }' math.txt
```

The `$0` represents the entire line that is read line by line from the file.

Additionally, it is not susceptible to nasty injections. It will only evaluate a line as a floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

Just feed the mess to `bc -l`, it will return one line result for each line of expression.
(The `-l` loads the math library, it also sets `scale` to a higher value and so gives fractional results.)