# Finding the average of 4 numbers awk script

Tags: awk, scripting

I created a script that adds four numbers that you enter:
Example:

```
./myawkaverage 8 7 9 4 
28
```

I need my script to add those four number and display the average so the results look like this:

Example:

```
./myawkaverage 8 7 9 4
The average is 7
```

I also need the script to accept negative numbers.

My script so far looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $2 $3 $4 | awk '
  {
    print sum3($1, $2, $3, $4)
  }
  function sum3(a, b, c, d) {
    return (a + b + c + d)
  }'
```

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/117549

Answer (score 1):

Without error checking and use of a user-defined `awk` function, you could simplify the script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $2 $3 $4 | awk '{sum=0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i; print sum}'
```

or if you do not need to always output a number even if zero:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $2 $3 $4 | awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i; print sum}'
```

Comment: Also see `print sum+0` instead of initializing sum to 0.

Comment: Thanks fpmurphy!

Answer (score 1):

Naming a function that sums **4** numbers "sum**3**" is an interesting choice, as is naming a script that **sums** numbers "myawk**average**" :-). Anyway...:

```
$ cat myawkaverage
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf '%s\n' "$@" | awk '{sum+=$0} END{print sum}'

$ ./myawkaverage 8 7 9 4
28

$ ./myawkaverage 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
66
```

and if you're actually trying to write a script to get averages then:

```
$ cat ./myawkaverage
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf '%s\n' "$@" |
awk -v n="$#" '{sum+=$0} END{ave=(n ? sum / n : "NaN"); print sum, ave}'


$ ./myawkaverage 8 7 9 4
28 7

$ ./myawkaverage 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
66 6

$ ./myawkaverage 0
0 0

$ ./myawkaverage
0 NaN
```

Comment: Using `NR` instead of `-v n` would also work, as the values arrive one-per-line.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant no, that'd fail when the script is called with no arguments because the `printf` would generate an empty line so within awk NR would be 1 while n is 0. There are other ways it could be handled of course.

Comment: It will print 0 instead of NaN, but avoids the test in the END case. The OP "guaranteed" there would be 4 numbers, of course. I would probably test `$#` up front to give a clearer user diagnostic (NaN->Babushka->Grandmother).

Comment: Right and I prefer to print NaN (or Inf) and I prefer not to test `$#` outside of the awk script as I prefer to have the output generated in only 1 place, inside the awk script. But there are several ways to handle it.