# BASH: arithmetic expressions on point values

Tags: bash, arithmetic

I am looking for bash function suitable to do some simple arithmetic expressions on point values
For intance

```
i=1
let "i_mod=${i}+1"; echo $i_mod
gives me 2

but if
i=1.0
let "i_mod=${i}+0.5";echo $i_mod
gives me an error instead of 1.5
```

or alternatively one of the sollution that has already been suggested in other topic:

```
i=1.0
echo "$(($i+1.0))"
-bash: 1.0+1.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0+1.0")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks)

Comment: not exactly! I've tried one of the sollution proposed for BASH and it did no work ( I edited my post..

Comment: The solution you have updated, says "(ksh93/zsh/yash, some bash)", not "bash". But there are many other examples into this post. For example: `echo "$i + 1.0" | bc`  or `bc <<< "$i + 1.0"` is enough. You can use scale with `bc` also. You can use `awk`. etc. In general, the shell is not for arithmetics by its own.

Comment: I mean "floating point arithmetics" (correction to my last comment) For integers you can just use the bash arithmetic expansion `(( ))`.

Comment: thank you so much !!  l=$(echo "$i + 1.0" | bc) works fine !!