# Convert string to number

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

i have the following SNMP Command

```
snmpget -v 1 -c COMMUNITY -t 2 HOST:161  1.3.6.1.4.1.24681.1.2.1.0 | awk '{print $4 $4}' | sed 's/.\(.*\)...../\1/'
```

that returns a string

```
9.10
```

what is percent value in the worng decimal.

I want to multiplicate this with 10 to make it correct:

```
91.0
```

How can I do this with the command above?

Thanks!
John

---

The `snmpget` command outputs the string

```
iso.3.6.1.4.1.24681.1.2.1.0 = STRING: "9.10 %"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks)

Comment: `awk '{print $4 $4}'` seems strange...

Comment: Welcome to the site. For future reference, please be sure to add the "raw" output of the command whose output you are text-processing, so that contributors can more easily track down the origin of unwanted output behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one `awk` command like this:

```bsh
# Use two sepatators, <space> and ", so you catch exactly the number.
# Multiply by 10
# `printf` allows you to format numbers in many ways, in this case, 1 decimal

str='iso.3.6.1.4.1.24681.1.2.1.0 = STRING: "9.10 %"'

$ echo "$str" | awk -F'[ "]' '{ printf "%.1f\n", $5*10 }'
91.0
```

Or as pointed out by [@Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas), this works too:

```
echo "$str" | awk -F \" '{ printf "%.1f\n", $2*10 }'
```

---

[Modifiers for printf Formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html)

> **%e, %E, %f, %F**
> Number of digits to the right of the decimal point.`

Comment: Worked, thahnk you!