# My calculation is getting converted to integer by default(KSH)

Tags: ksh, floating-point

I am assigning a decimal value to a variable which is an output from an oracle command. when I echo the variable I see the decimal value.

For example, echo $a is showing me .7214 but when I do calculations on this, it is defaulted to integer.

For example, b=$((a+(a*20/100))) is rounding to 1.

How do I avoid rounding this to integer.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/117549

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```bsh
b=$( echo "$a+($a*0.02)" | bc )
```