# >= unary operator expected or -eq integer expression expected

Tags: bash, scripting, macos, macintosh, character-encoding

```
monterey2="12.0"
macOS=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
if [ "$macOS" >= "$monterey2" ] ; then
  echo "Monterey"
else 
  echo "not Monterey"
fi
exit 0
```

Ouputs this error -> "[: 12.2.1: unary operator expected".. I've tried -eq as well with same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Echo the two version numbers into `sort -V` and see which number comes out first (as text). If it matches `$monterey2` as text, then the one from `sw_vers` is greater or equal.

Float comparisons do not work on version numbers, because the individual parts are integers (and not necessarily only two of them). Examples:

```
12.3 is earlier than 12.10
12.3.11 is later that 12.3.8
```

Comment: and string sorting order comparisons also don't work, for pretty much similar reasons.

Comment: @ilkkachu  I had forgotten how smart `sort -V` is. It will handle alpha in version numbers too, and allows `-f` to fold upper/lower in such cases.

Comment: yeah I meant that simple string comparison like plain `sort` or `[[ a < b ]]` fail same as simple numeric comparisons. `sort -V` is another thing entirely, it even supports Debian's tilde-suffixes for pre-versions (`1.2~rc1` < `1.2` < `1.2-foo`). Well, at least the one on Debian does. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Under `[`, only `>` is supported for string comparison, not `>=`. For numeric comparison, you can use `-ge`, but `12.2.1` is not an integer, so it's not valid for numeric operators.

If you want to check for Monterey only, use `=` (string equality):

```
if [ "$macOS" = "$monterey2" ] ; then
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do want it to be "is greater than or equal to".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `test` can only understand integers or strings but you want to compare floating point numbers. I'd suggest using `bc` to get the comparison result.

In particular, change this:

```
if [ "$macOS" >= "$monterey2" ] ; then
```

To this:

```
if [ $(echo "$macOS >= $monterey2" | bc) ]; then
```

### EDIT

This actually won't work in your situation where the version numbers have more than one decimal like `12.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     if [ "$macOS" >= "$monterey2" ] ; then
> ```
>
> Ouputs this error -> "[: 12.2.1: unary operator expected"..
> What am I doing wrong?

This happens because `[` is a *normal command*, and so `>` works in the usual way as the redirection operator. The word after that, `=`, is taken as the file name, and both are removed before they're passed to the `[` command. So, if you have in effect e.g.
`[ 12.2.1 >= 12.0 ]`, it's similar to `[ 12.2.1 12.0 ] > outputfile`, just with an odder filename and more confusing ordering.

`[` sees two arguments before the closing `]`, so it expects a unary operator and the operand to it. That would be stuff like e.g. `[ -f xyz ]` to check if `xyz` is an existing regular file. Of course, `12.2.1` isn't a valid operator, so you get the error. Also, you'll find that file called `=` in the directory you ran the script in.

> I've tried -eq as well with same result.

Well, it's not the same result, since the error message is "integer expression expected", as you mentioned in the question title. Bash only does integer arithmetic, and your values aren't integers. There's workarounds in [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/170373)

*However*, as other answers mention, you can't compare version numbers as decimal / floating point numbers anyway. While `12.0` is a number, `12.2.1` isn't.