# Replicating floating point arithmetic WITHOUT bc utility

Tags: bash, arithmetic, floating-point

I'm needing to write a script on some embedded Linux systems that don't have `bc` installed on them and won't be able to have it installed. The script I'm writing is essentially a monitoring script that takes certain corrective actions at different load values. For example, at load average 1.5, do something.

I am wondering if there's a simple way to take the load average variable and just multiply it by 100 *or* simply move the decimal place to the right two spaces and pad with 0s if necessary, that would then make this integer arithmetic and normal bash (()) arithmetic expansion could take over.

Right now, I'm breaking the floating point number its truncated integer and the decimal as a whole number(e.g. 1.5, LOAD1_INT=1, LOAD1_DECIMAL=50) but would like to simplify it if possible.

Current (complicated) version:

```bsh
CRIT_LOAD=3.5
if [[ $CRIT_LOAD =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}$ ]]; then
    # Since bash can't handle floating point arithmetic, break $CRIT_LOAD float into 2 separate integers
    CRIT_LOAD_INT=$(echo $CRIT_LOAD | cut -d'.' -f1)
    CRIT_LOAD_DECIMAL=$(echo $CRIT_LOAD | cut -d'.' -f2)
elif [[ $CRIT_LOAD =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}$ ]]; then
    # If $CRIT_LOAD is already an int, update variables so Monitor code works unchanged
    CRIT_LOAD_INT=$CRIT_LOAD
    CRIT_LOAD_DECIMAL=0
else
    # Set a default value of 1.0 if we can't parse CRIT_LOAD value
    CRIT_LOAD_INT=1
    CRIT_LOAD_DECIMAL=0
fi
LOAD1=$(cat /proc/loadavg | cut -d' ' -f1)
LOAD1_INT=$(echo $LOAD1 | cut -d'.' -f1)
LOAD1_DECIMAL=$(echo $LOAD1 | cut -d'.' -f2)

# Current load int is already higher than critical threshold int
if (( LOAD1_INT > CRIT_LOAD_INT )); then
    log "CRITICAL: Load values have exceeded threshold."
elif (( LOAD1_INT == CRIT_LOAD_INT )); then
    # If current load int is same as crit threshold int, compare decimals
    if (( LOAD1_DECIMAL > CRIT_LOAD_DECIMAL )); then
        log "CRITICAL: Load values have exceeded threshold."
    fi
fi
```

Is there a way to just pare down all this code by simply turning loadavg (e.g. 1.50) into an int (e.g. 150)? Again, *without* using the `bc` utility as it't not available on these systems.

**EDIT:** I wound up taking the `printf` command @ilkkachu suggested and modified it into a function for use in my code. I chose this route over the `awk` command as there are other places in this code where calling a function to emulate floating point arithmetic simplifies code readability and re-usability. Marking his answer as solution.

```
function dec_to_int() {
    DECIMAL=$1
    SCALE_FACTOR=$2
    # printf removes decimal and allows $SCALE_FACTOR additional spaces to be included, 0-pads numbers that would be too small otherwise
    # NOTE: printf will round number if the values it keeps are greater than the scale factor
    # e.g. SCALE_FACTOR=2, 1.759 -> 176
    SCALED_INT=$(printf "%.0f\n" "${DECIMAL}e${SCALE_FACTOR}")
    echo $SCALED_INT
}

LOAD1=$(cat /proc/loadavg | cut -d' ' -f1)
LOAD1=$(dec_to_int $LOAD1 2)
```

Comment: Does your system have awk, perl, python, nodejs, ruby, zsh?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a matter of testing against `^(3\.[6-9]|[4-9]\.|[0-9]{2,}\.)`? Or something similar.

Comment: @jesse_b even Debian doesn't have `bc` installed out of the box. See also `pax` and `m4` which are often omitted.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, even Debian have `awk` installed :D

Comment: Your numerical comparison of the DECIMAL part works only if the number of decimal digits is the same. When you have e.g. `3.5` and `3.25`, you might get an unexpected result if you compare `5` with `25`.

Comment: My system has awk and gnu sed both, those or printf seemed like it might be the option that could move the decimal point over (and possibly 0 pad the end if needed) but I haven't been able to come up with something that works. 

That's a great catch on the decimal point only working if it has a value in the hundreths place as well, I can fix that with another conditional but this is just further evidence to me that I need to simplify this by moving the decimal point to the right two places.

Comment: `awk` is probably your best bet but you can turn a decimal to a scaled integer with `printf "%.2f" 3.5 | tr -d .`.

Comment: You can just compare the numbers as is with awk.  `awk -v load1_int="$load1_int" -v crit_load_int="$crit_load_int" 'BEGIN{if (load1_int > crit_load_int) { ... }}'`

Comment: as an aside, the standard way to declare a function is `dec_to_int()`, without the `function` keyword (it's a ksh thing), and while Bash supports it too, not all shells might (e.g. Dash and Busybox don't), and there's no upside. Also, if you're on Bash, you can use `printf -v SCALED_INT  "%.0f\n" "${DECIMAL}e${SCALE_FACTOR}"` instead of `SCALED_INT=$(printf ...)`, it saves spawning a copy of the shell for the command substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want/need to do it purely in Bash (or even Dash or Busybox), you can
take a page from [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/170373) and
abuse the fact that `printf` should be able to parse a floating point number and print it another out. Appending a suffix like `e2` would scale the number up by 100 (as long as the number doesn't already have an E-suffix).

E.g. this would print `a` scaled up by 100, or `123`:

```
a=1.23
printf "%.0f\n" "${a}e2"
```

Or, reading from `/proc/loadavg`:

```
read avg1 avg5 avg15 rest < /proc/loadavg
scaled_load=$(printf "%.0f\n" "${avg1}e2")
```

(or `printf -v scaled_load "%.0f\n" "${avg1}e2"` instead of the command substitution in Bash)

Then again, as long as `loadavg` contains only two digits after the decimal point, you could just drop the point from the middle and turn `1.23` directly into `123`.

The linked post contains a few other programs that can also be used for floating point arithmetic. Even if your installation doesn't have `bc`, it might have e.g. `awk`.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your code correct, you want to log a message when the first value of `/proc/loadavg` is greater than `CRIT_LOAD`. This check including the parsing of `/proc/loadavg` can be done with a single `awk` command.

```
if ! awk -v crit_load=3.5 '$1>crit_load { exit 1 }' /proc/loadavg
then
    log "CRITICAL: Load values have exceeded threshold."
fi
```

The `awk` script reads (all lines from) `/proc/loadavg` and if the first field is greater than `crit_load` it exits with code 1 (error, false), otherwise it exits with code 0 (OK, true).

If the threshold value is already in a shell variable you can, of course, use this for the `awk` variable assignment.

```
CRIT_LOAD=3.5
if ! awk -v crit_load="$CRIT_LOAD" '$1>crit_load { exit 1 }' /proc/loadavg
then # ...
```

If necessary, the `awk` script could be extended to check other fields `/proc/loadavg` as well. This would be more efficient and consistent than running several `awk` commands and combining the results in the shell script.

If you want to distinguish more cases, the script can be changed to use different exit codes.

```
awk -v crit_load=3.5 -v warn_load=1.5 '$1>crit_load { exit 2 } $1>warn_load { exit 1 }' /proc/loadavg
case "$?" in
    2) do_something ;;
    1) do_other ;;
    0) do_nothing ;;
    *) handle_unknown_value ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have dc?

Otherwise maybe something like this. It takes the first two decimals after the dot. It then takes the integer and multiplies it by 100, after which the two decimals (which are now not decimals anymore) are added up to that number.

```
loadavg="1.50"
mult100="100"
DECIMALS=$( echo "${loadavg#*.}" | cut -c 1-2 )
INT=$( echo $loadavg | cut -f 1 -d . )
NEW_INT=$(( $INT * $mult100 ))
NEW_LOADAVG=$(( $NEW_INT + $DECIMALS ))
echo "$NEW_LOADAVG"
```

No printf required. Works also with larger numbers.

```
loadavg="147372.52772830"
mult100="100"
DECIMALS=$( echo "${loadavg#*.}" | cut -c 1-2 )
INT=$( echo $loadavg | cut -f 1 -d . )
NEW_INT=$(( $INT * $mult100 ))
NEW_LOADAVG=$(( $NEW_INT + $DECIMALS ))
echo "$NEW_LOADAVG"
```

It always rounds down; just multiplication of number by 100 and removing the leftover decimals.

If it needs to be rounded to nearest integer, then use

```
loadavg="147372.52772830"
mult100="100"
DECIMALS=$( echo "${loadavg#*.}" | cut -c 1-2 )
INT=$( echo $loadavg | cut -f 1 -d . )
NEW_INT=$(( $INT * $mult100 ))
ROUNDING=$( echo "${loadavg#*.}" | cut -c 3 )
if [[ $ROUNDING -ge 5 ]]; then NEW_LOADAVG=$(( $NEW_INT + $DECIMALS + 1 )); else NEW_LOADAVG=$(( $NEW_INT + $DECIMALS )); fi
echo "$NEW_LOADAVG"
```

If it needs to be rounded up, then use

```
loadavg="147372.52772830"
mult100="100"
DECIMALS=$( echo "${loadavg#*.}" | cut -c 1-2 )
INT=$( echo $loadavg | cut -f 1 -d . )
NEW_INT=$(( $INT * $mult100 ))
ROUNDING=$( echo "${loadavg#*.}" | cut -c 3 )
if [[ $ROUNDING -gt 0 ]]; then NEW_LOADAVG=$(( $NEW_INT + $DECIMALS + 1 )); else NEW_LOADAVG=$(( $NEW_INT + $DECIMALS )); fi
echo "$NEW_LOADAVG"
```

edit: ah solved already -_-'

Comment: (1) You have overlooked a potential problem identified in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702743/replicating-floating-point-arithmetic-without-bc-utility/716045#comment1328899_702743) by Bodo — `1.7` will be treated as if it were `1.07`. You can fix this by saying `DECIMALS=$( echo "${loadavg#*.}00" | cut -c 1-2 )` (note the added `00`). (2) IMHO, the `NEW_INT` variable just makes this longer and more cumbersome, and not more clear. I suggest `NEW_LOADAVG=$(( $INT * $mult100 + $DECIMALS ))`, or `$(( ( $INT * $mult100 ) + $DECIMALS ))` if you want to be pedantic. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2a) I do not see much benefit in having the `mult100` variable.  Oh, sure, next week the requirement might be to handle four decimal places, and so you’d want to multiply the integer part by 10,000 — but would you really want to change the definition of `mult100` to be 10000?  That would be terribly confusing.  I you suggest that you define `POW=2` and `TEN_POW=100` — maybe even *compute* `TEN_POW` from `POW` — then change `cut -c 1-2` to `cut -c 1-"$POW"`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) I believe that your rounding code is more complicated than it needs to be.  I suggest `NEW_LOADAVG=$(( $INT * $mult100 + $DECIMALS ))`, then `if [[ $ROUNDING -ge 5 ]]; then (( NEW_LOADAVG++ )); fi`.  (4) Your up-rounding code will round 3.0077 up to 3.01, but 3.0007 down to 3.00 (should also be 3.01).

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) If your input (`loadavg`) is something like `.72`, then `INT` will be set to an empty string.  Of course, this will cause subsequent calculations to fail.  (You should test for that and set it to `0`.) … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … PS.  System-defined variables, like `HOME` and `PATH`, typically have names that are all upper case.  Therefore, it is commonly advised not to use all-upper-case names for user-defined variables, to reduce the chance of collision.